# Using property method with setter prevents function from binding to object attribute

Tags: python

I am attempting to use a property-based method to control the class constructor (screening for bad values at instance creation time), in this code. For some reason I don't understand the function `set_sequence` won't alter the derived class Binary object's attribute `seq` when called from the `@num.setter` method - it has to be called elsewhere. Am I missing something basic about how properties work?

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

class Binary(Number):
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__(num)
        self.seq = ()

    @property
    def num(self):
        return self._num

    @num.setter
    def num(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError('Unsigned numbers cannot be negative')
        self._num = value
        self.set_sequence() #this calls the function, but the value doesn't get bound

    def set_sequence(self):
        print('called ', end='')
        self.seq = tuple([int(x) for x in bin(self.num)[2:]])
```

Calling this code as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n1 = Binary(11)
    print(f"{n1.num} = {n1.seq}")
    n1.set_sequence()            
    print(f"{n1.num} = {n1.seq}")
```

Gives:

```
called 11 = ()
called 11 = (1, 0, 1, 1)
```

This throws an exception as expected when negative values are passed to constructor, but I don't understand why the function call fails to behave as expected. This pattern is based on Brett Slatkin's Item#29 in 'Effective Python' incidentally, the part about using @property to do type checking and value validation when the constructor is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in your constructor after `super().__init__(num)` that calls your `@num.setter` you use `self.seq = ()` that overrides the value stored in your setter method.

Answer (score 1):

To have the desired output, you should do like this. In you example `self.set_sequence()` is overridden by the second instruction in the constructor.

```py
class Number:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

class Binary(Number):

    seq = ()

    def __init__(self, num):
        # or eventually here
        # seq = ()
        super().__init__(num)

    @property
    def num(self):
        return self._num

    @num.setter
    def num(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError('Unsigned numbers cannot be negative')
        self._num = value
        self.set_sequence() #this calls the function, but the value doesn't get bound

    def set_sequence(self):
        print('called ', end='')
        self.seq = tuple([int(x) for x in bin(self.num)[2:]])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n1 = Binary(11)
    print(f"{n1.num} = {n1.seq}")
    n1.set_sequence()            
    print(f"{n1.num} = {n1.seq}")
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to make a class-level attribute of ```seq```? I just commented out the constructor assignment and let the set_sequence function do that, it seems to work fine?

Comment: Yes, to make your code more clear you should define it as a class level attribute. Moreover, since that is the "main attribute" of your class, don't you think it should be explicitly visible from outside? If you don't define it somehow, for example, using an editor you wouldn't know that `seq` exists. See also `__slots__` http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/__slots__magic.html